# How to add filter to pointcloud_to_laserscan package and depthimage_to_laserscan package

Tags: ros-kinetic, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to add filters to my `pointcloud` and `depthimage` data before converting them to `laserscan` data due to noise. Seeing as there are  weel knwon packages (pointcloud-to-laserscan, depthimage-to-laserscan) that do these conversions, I was thinking to modify the source code of these packages by adding a median filter for instance,in the case of depthimage. Looking at the source code of the [pointcloud-to-laserscan](https://github.com/ros-perception/pointcloud_to_laserscan/blob/indigo-devel/src/pointcloud_to_laserscan_nodelet.cpp) package for instance, it's unclear where in the code I can implement the filter, if that's possible. Does anyone have experience with this? or is there an easier way about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409005/how-to-add-filter-to-pointcloud_to_laserscan-package-and-depthimage_to_laserscan-package/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly do you mean by filtering here?

The whole transformation seems to happen in this callback:

- https://github.com/ros-perception/pointcloud_to_laserscan/blob/1f4e90539e4d2c3d05b8dfe022d03008f322d37b/src/pointcloud_to_laserscan_nodelet.cpp#L139

So it is the place you should look into - IF it is needed. Perhaps you can achieve what you want with e.g.
`message_filters` package (e.g. cache last N messages and publish it every second as a median etc.)?

- http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-11-06**:
@ljaniec I want to remove outliers that dont make sense basically. What I'm getting from message filter is it gets a bunch of different messages(stores each type of message in cache) and realeses the data for use if some conditions are met. THis isn't quite what I want. For instance a median filter in the case of depth image simply simply targets anomaly pixels and replaces them with the average value of the pixels around them.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-11-06**:
So it should be a node that transforms a pointcloud (remove outliers) and feeds these transformed pointclouds to the pointcloud-to-laserscan package. Perhaps these transformations also can be done with the laserscan (so after the pointcloud-to-laserscan transformation). Modyfing the code is not necessary here, just a new nodelet.

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-11-06**:
@ljaniec you mean using packages like [this?](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters)

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-11-06**:
Yes, pretty much. If this answer helped you, please mark & upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it makes more sense to create another nodelet implementing the filter you propose, and chaining it in between the camera driver and pointcloud-to-laserscan or depthimage-to-laserscan. Using nodelets means that the performance won't get reduced by publishing / subscribing, and the code will be reusable for other use cases.

Indeed, I would be surprised if there aren't filters already available as open source. If not, it would make a nice contribution to https://github.com/ros-perception

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2022-11-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-11-08**:
@jorge I've been trying to get the laser_filter to work, how do I chain it between a cmaera driver and the other packages?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2022-11-08**:
What I understood is that you have a noisy 3D camera and you want to filter the pointcloud or the depth images. For that, you need to find or write a filter nodelet for each case, and chain with publish-subscribe (represented as  ----> here), e.g.

```
cam driver    ---->    point cloud filter   ---->      pointcloud-to-laserscan
cam driver    ---->    depth image filter   ---->      depthimage-to-laserscan
```